# Django image isn't uploaded by using javascript node from markup string

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, file-upload

I created django dynamic forms that work on click, but I don't get why the image isn't uploaded.

I didn't have request.FILES and added that. I also added enctype="multipart/form-data" but it didn't help too.

So this is my template code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Vote/style.css' %}" />
<fieldset id="fieldset">
    <form method = 'POST' action = '' enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ voteTypeForm }}</p>
        <div id="placeholder">

        </div>
        <p>
            <button type="button" name="Submit" onclick="Add();">+</button>
        </p>
        <input type = 'submit' value="create"/>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<script type='text/javascript'>
{#    document.write(code);#}
    var _counter = 0;
    var template = document.createTextNode('');
    function appendStringAsNodes(element, html)
    {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            tmp = document.createElement('body'), child;
        tmp.innerHTML = html;
        // Append elements in a loop to a DocumentFragment, so that the browser does
        // not re-render the document for each node
        while (child = tmp.firstChild) {
            frag.appendChild(child);
        }
        element.appendChild(frag); // Now, append all elements at once
        frag = tmp = null;
    }
    function Add() {
        var code = '<div id="template">' +
                '<p>' +
                    '<fieldset id="fieldsets">' +
                        '<legend id="legends">Candidate No ['+ String(_counter+1) +']</legend>' +
                       ' <form method = "POST" action = "" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
                              '<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{csrf_token }}" />' +
                            '<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" maxlength="50" name="name" type="text" /></p>'+
                            '<p><label for="id_image">Image:</label> <input id="id_image" name="image" type="file"/></p>'+
                        '</form>' +
                   ' </fieldset>' +
                '</p>'
            '</div>';
        _counter++;
        appendStringAsNodes(document.getElementById("placeholder"),code);
        document.getElementById("someInput").value = _counter;
    }
</script>
```

this is my views.py code:

```
def voting(request,pk):
    voting_num = VoteType.objects.get(pk=pk).vote_set.count()
    if voting_num >= 2:
        Voted1 = VoteType.objects.get(pk=pk).vote_set.order_by('?').first()
        Voted2 = VoteType.objects.get(pk=pk).vote_set.order_by('?')[2]
        while Voted1 == Voted2:
            Voted2 = Vote.objects.order_by('?')[2]
        context = RequestContext(request, {
            'voted1': Voted1,
            'voted2': Voted2,
            'voting_num': voting_num
        })
    else:
        context = RequestContext(request, {
            'voting_num': voting_num
        })

    return render(request, 'Vote/voting.html', context)
```

I write

```
print voteTypeForm.is_valid()
        print voteForm.is_valid()
        something = request.FILES.get('image')
        print request.FILES
        print something
```

the printed data is:

```
True
False
<MultiValueDict: {}>
None
```

why isn't the file uploaded?

I checked and added the image upload code in html instead of putting it in javascript code. When I do so, it is working perfectly, but when I try to put it in the javascript **'code'** variable and use it in appendStringNodes, than it doesn't work. so the problem should be in javascript. how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you verified that the image file is being posted via something like FireBug or Chrome's Dev Tools?

Comment: when I do it in javascript the file isn't even being posted. but when I copied  code up in html than it did post and everything worked fine. but that way I won't be able to create forms dynamically.

Comment: Does removing the form from the dynamic javascript work? You have a wrapping form around everything.

Comment: u mean the form around the inputs?

Comment: Yes. You have a form inside the ```code``` var and then another form wrapping the placeholder div.

Comment: Now I get different error, but I think it worked. let me fix that error to verify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82706/discussion-between-vato-and-schillingt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @schillingt answered in comments. the problem was in having another  in javascript code. After taking that away. the problem was solved.

this is my code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Vote/style.css' %}" />
<fieldset id="fieldset">
    <form method = 'POST' action = '' enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ voteTypeForm }}</p>
        <div id="placeholder">
{#        <p><label for="id_image">Image:</label> <input id="id_image" name="image" type="file"/></p>#}
        </div>
        <p>
            <button type="button" name="Submit" onclick="Add();">+</button>
        </p>
        <input type = 'submit' value="create"/>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<script type='text/javascript'>
{#    document.write(code);#}
    var _counter = 0;
    var template = document.createTextNode('');
    function appendStringAsNodes(element, html)
    {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            tmp = document.createElement('body'), child;
        tmp.innerHTML = html;
        // Append elements in a loop to a DocumentFragment, so that the browser does
        // not re-render the document for each node
        while (child = tmp.firstChild) {
            frag.appendChild(child);
        }
        element.appendChild(frag); // Now, append all elements at once
        frag = tmp = null;
    }
    function Add() {
        var code = '<div id="template">' +
                '<p>' +
                    '<fieldset id="fieldsets">' +
                        '<legend id="legends">Candidate No ['+ String(_counter+1) +']</legend>' +
{#                       ' <form method = "POST" action = "" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+#}
                              '<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{csrf_token }}" />' +
                            '<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" maxlength="50" name="name" type="text" /></p>'+
                            '<p><label for="id_image">Image:</label> <input id="id_image" name="image" type="file"/></p>'+
{#                        '</form>' +#}
                   ' </fieldset>' +
                '</p>'
            '</div>';
        _counter++;
        appendStringAsNodes(document.getElementById("placeholder"),code);
        document.getElementById("someInput").value = _counter;
    }
</script>
```

Thx for help @schillingt